# How to passing xmlHttp by classic asp in youtube API v3

Tags: asp.net

```
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URLString = "https://www.googleapis.com"
Call xmlHttp.open("POST", URLString, False)
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("POST", "/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2status%2contentDetails HTTP/1.1")
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Host", "www.googleapis.com")
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "& ACCESS_TOKEN)
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", Len(jsonString))
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-Upload-Content-Length", 2000)
Call xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-Upload-Content-Type", "video/*")
Call xmlHttp.Send(jsonString)
```

If xmlHttp.Status >= 400 And xmlHttp.Status <= 599 Then
    Response.Write "
Error Occured : " & xmlHttp.statusText
Response.End
End If

I wrote code like that

but response is 404 error

```
        POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN
Content-Length: 278
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Length: 3000000
X-Upload-Content-Type: video/*
{
  "snippet": {
    "title": "My video title",
    "description": "This is a description of my video",
    "tags": ["cool", "video", "more keywords"],
    "categoryId": 22
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "embeddable": True,
    "license": "youtube"
  }
}
```

it is correct post request

How can I do?